# Passing a nested enum as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift2, uifont

I can't think of a way to retrieve the raw value from a nested enum in the convenience init. `fontName.rawValue` won't work since `Custom` has no cases. Any suggestions?

```
extension UIFont {
    enum Custom {
        enum Roboto: String {
            case Regular = "RobotoRegular"
        }
        enum SanFrancisco: String {
            case Semibold = "SFSemibold"
        }
    }

    convenience init?(name fontName: Custom, size fontSize: CGFloat) {
        self.init(name: fontName.rawValue, size: fontSize)
    }
}

// Example Usage
UIFont(name: .Roboto.Regular, size: 18)
```

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve with nesting the enums like this?

Comment: Nested enums provide better autocompletion result.

Comment: @efremidze forced unwrap like self.init(...)! is the worst idea which i have ever seen.

Comment: @user3441734 Yes I agree, just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest alternative implementation:

```
protocol CustomFontsProtocol {
    func size(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont?
}

extension CustomFontsProtocol where Self: RawRepresentable, Self.RawValue == String {
    func size(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont(name: rawValue, size: size)
    }
}

enum CustomFonts {
    enum Roboto: String, FontConvertible {
        case Regular = "RobotoRegular"
    }
    enum SanFrancisco: String, FontConvertible {
        case Semibold = "SFSemibold"
    }
}

// Example Usage
CustomFonts.SanFrancisco.Semibold.size(18)
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly different approach you could take, but would make using the fonts just as easy. First you need to create a protocol for your font enumeration and then an extension to provide a default method, like this:

```
protocol CustomFontsProtocol {
    var fontName: String { get }
}

extension CustomFontsProtocol {
    func size(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: size)!
    }
}
```

Now for your enum you can create it like this:

```
enum CustomFonts {
    enum Roboto: CustomFontsProtocol {
        case Regular

        var fontName: String {
            switch self {
            case Regular: return "RobotoRegular"
            }
        }
    }

    enum SanFrancisco: CustomFontsProtocol {
        case Semibold

        var fontName: String {
            switch self {
            case Semibold: return "SFSemibold"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will then allow you to call your fonts like this:

```
CustomFonts.SanFrancisco.Semibold.size(18)
```

Comment: Using protocols like this was my alternative